# Undefined symbol _main, however I do have a main function?

Tags: c, gcc

Here is my console output:

```
Tylers-MacBook-Pro:laser_finder_c tylerjw$ make
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o dots_img.o dots_img.c
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o no_dots_img.o no_dots_img.c
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o point.o point.c
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o images.o images.c
gcc -g -Wall   -c -o laser_finder_c.o laser_finder_c.c
gcc dots_img.o no_dots_img.o point.o images.o laser_finder_c.o  -g -Wall -o laser_finder_c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [laser_finder_c] Error 1
```

This doesn't seem to make any sense as the main function is defined in `laser_finder_c.c`.  Below is my makefile.  I'm real confused as to why this is happening.

```
TARGET      = laser_finder_c
OBJECTS     = dots_img.o no_dots_img.o point.o images.o laser_finder_c.o 
#######################################################################################
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall
ASFLAGS  = -Wall
LDFLAGS  = -g -Wall

CC = gcc
AS = gcc

########################################################################################
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(TARGET)

point.o: point.h
images.o: images.h
laser_finder_c.o: images.h point.h
dots_img.o: images.h
no_dots_img.o: images.h

clean: 
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

Here is the definition of main in laser_finder_c.c

```
// laser_finder.c - finds the location of laser points comparing two images
#include "point.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// #defines ... removed

int main()
{
  // ... code removed

  return 0;
}
```

For context the output of `gcc -v` is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Please show the main function in `laser_finder_c.c`, or at least the declaration (the function body isn't essential).

Comment: You should show the relevant files. Can you come up with a smaller set of code that produces the same behaviour (minimal example)?

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting the error from clang.  You can see that I'm clearly telling it to use gcc in my make file.

Comment: Could it be that you're defining `main` wrong? Try using the signature `int main(void)` instead and see what happens. Looks like the error happens at link time.

Comment: do an objdump -d to your laser_finder_c.o to see if it contains a _main symbol. If it does, it's possibly for the wrong architecture? Check with "file".

If that would be the case, you should check your installation.

Comment: I get an error that objdump command can't be found by bash.  However I got it to compile by changing the order of the objects in the makefile so the one with main is listed first when linking.  Any idea's what would cause that?  I've never had to do that before to get projects to compile.

Comment: I used `nm` instead of `objdump` since I don't have `objdump` on my mac and `_main` is one of the symbols.

Comment: @tylerjw, like Herman said, try `int main(void)`

Comment: @SeanPedersen, thank you, I changed it to be that.  That even worked after putting back the object with main to be the last in the link command.

Comment: @HermanTorjussen: You should really add this as an answer!

Comment: @tylerjw: You observed this on which OS, using exactly which compiler/linker? Would you mind updating the question's tags accordingly?

Comment: @HermanTorjussen: `int main(void)` is preferred over `int main()`, but gcc accepts both. That's not the problem.

Comment: Make a copy of your project and start removing and/or shrinking source files, with the goal of creating a minimal example that exhibits the problem. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Can you compile a simple "hello, world" program? `gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o ; gcc hello.o -o hello ; ./hello`

Comment: I can compile a simple "hello, world" program.  I've tried reducing the code to produce the issue but it seems to happen randomly.  I can't figure out how to consistently reproduce the problem.  When it does happen if I make clean and rebuild everything it usually fixes it.  Sometimes I have to do it twice.

Comment: This is real frustrating because right now I can't get it to generate the error and nothing has been changed in the project.